# How to get the property name of object and use that property name in javascript

Tags: javascript, object

I have an object named: `mapped_errors` that returns a dynamic object.

sometimes its value is:

```
{ _id:
   { location: 'body',
     param: '_id',
     value: 123,
     msg: '_id is required and must be a string' } }
```

and sometimes its value is:

```
{ _name:
   { location: 'body',
     param: '_name',
     value: 123,
     msg: '_name is required and must be a string' } }
```

and i want to output the `msg` value something like this:

```
let obj_key = Object.keys(mapped_errors);
console.log(mapped_errors.{obj_key}.msg); // i know this is wrong
```

;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only error in your code is `mapped_errors.{obj_key}.msg`. You should be using `[]` to access the object's property value when you are using a variable to get the key name, as `mapped_errors[obj_key]`.

```js
var mapped_errors = { _id:
   { location: 'body',
     param: '_id',
     value: 123,
     msg: '_id is required and must be a string' } };

let obj_key = Object.keys(mapped_errors);
console.log(mapped_errors[obj_key].msg);

mapped_errors = { _name:
   { location: 'body',
     param: '_name',
     value: 123,
     msg: '_name is required and must be a string' } }
     
obj_key = Object.keys(mapped_errors);
console.log(mapped_errors[obj_key].msg);
```

Comment: Oh i forgot that way. Haha. Thank you sir.

Comment: @noyruto88 glad to help

Answer (score 0):

Just loop your object using its keys:

```
Object.keys(mapped_errors).forEach(key => {
  const value = mapped_errors[key];

  console.log(value.msg);
})
```

Or if you don't want to loop because there will be just one entry, try with:

```
const key = Object.keys(mapped_errors)[0];

console.log(mapped_errors[key].msg);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the property exists `mapped_errors.hasOwnProperty('_name')`

You coud also access the first key like so: 

`var keys = Object.keys(mapped_errors);
console.log(mapped_errors[keys[0]])`

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

```js
let obj = { _id:
   { location: 'body',
     param: '_id',
     value: 123,
     msg: '_id is required and must be a string' } }

console.log(obj[Object.keys(obj)[0]].msg)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Object.keys` with index as per below

```js
mapped_errors = { _id:
   { location: 'body',
     param: '_id',
     value: 123,
     msg: '_id is required and must be a string' } };
     
console.log(mapped_errors[Object.keys(mapped_errors)[0]].msg);     
     
mapped_errors = { _name:
   { location: 'body',
     param: '_name',
     value: 123,
     msg: '_name is required and must be a string' } };

console.log(mapped_errors[Object.keys(mapped_errors)[0]].msg);
```

`Object.keys` returns the array of keys `[0]` will take first key and `mapped_errors[Object.keys(mapped_errors)[0]].msg` will return msg content.